# Displaying launch configuration type in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a setting or plugin which gives visual feedback about the currently launched configuration's type (i.e. whether it was debug or run)?

Comment: What are you launching?  The Eclipse you use to launch usually switches to a debug perspective when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug view can give you this information:

[image]

An application running in debug mode will include the list of running threads. In the above image, the first launched is in debug, the second in run.